# How do I identify a node as being a root node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I want to create a node inside or under an existing node depending on if it is a root node. (a tree widget is usually a list of trees or a tree without a visible root node.)

I tried get_parent, but how do I know if that is a root node?

```
var parent = $("#demo1").jstree('_get_parent', $("#foo"));
var node = $("#demo1").jstree('_get_node', $("#foo"));
```

What confused me is that get_node seems to return the same object as get_parent.

I'm using jstree_pre1.0_fix_1.

**edited:**

I ended up checking for the known id of the parent of the parent.

```
var node = $(e.replyto);
if (node.length) {
  if (node.parent().parent().attr('id') == 'demo1') {
    $("#demo1").jstree("create_node", node, 'last',{'attr': {'id':e.id}, 'state':'open', 'data': e.data}) ;
  } else {
    $("#demo1").jstree("create_node", node, 'after',{'attr': {'id':e.id}, 'state':'open', 'data': e.data}) ;
  }
} else {
    $("#demo1").jstree("create_node", -1, 'after',{'attr': {'id':e.id}, 'state':'open', 'data': e.data});
}
```

Comment: In most implementations parent of the root node is either `null`, or itself. Maybe, this is the case.

Comment: I edited the question and replace top level node with root node and tried to define it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [get_parent()](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_parent(obj)) on the node.  If it returns '#' then the node is a root node. E.G:

```
var node = ...;

if($('#demo1').jstree(true).get_parent(node) == '#') {
    // node is a root node
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the ideal solution but you can use `_get_children` with `-1` in param to get all root nodes and test if your node is in the list.

```
._get_children ( node )
  Use -1 to return all root nodes.
```

(from http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core)

Comment: Thanks. Good solution to get started with. If it is too slow to do a linear search on every insert I can tag them with an extra attribute when I insert the root nodes.

Comment: You can also retrieve the container with `get_container_ul()` and use the jQuery function [.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling a bit with this because I'm trying to use the context menu plugin.  I don't want the user to be able to create a new root node. I only want to allow them to create sub-nodes.  (The root nodes represent the groups that the current user belongs to so is pre-set by the administrator). My first confusion was that `_get_children` returns an object with a `length` property. It's not an array but it has a `length` property corresponding correctly to the number of actual root nodes. Looking at the underlying code, the `jstree` `_get_children` method uses jQuery's `children` method, which returns the child nodes with indexes 0, 1, 2 etc along with other jQuery properties and methods.  I found it convenient to extract just the array of nodes and use `indexOf` to check if the current node is a root node. So, here is a snippet from the `items` property of my `jstree` context menu configuration:

```
'items': function(node){
    var rootChildren = this._get_children(-1), 
    rootNodes = [], 
    i;
    //rootChildren is now a fancy jQuery object with the child nodes assigned
    //to keys 0, 1 etc.
    //Now create a simple array
    for(i = 0; i < rootChildren.length; i += 1){
        rootNodes[i] = rootChildren[i];
    }
    //We can now use indexOf to check if the current node is in that array
    //Note again that node is a fancy jQuery object, the actual DOM element
    //is stored in node[0]
    console.log(rootNodes.indexOf(node[0]) > -1);
    //code here to add whatever items you want to the context menu.
}
```

If you right click around your tree, you will see `true` in the console window for the root nodes and `false` for any nodes lower down the hierarchy. Note that for IE below 8 (I think), you will need to supply an `indexOf` method for `Array` because earlier versions of IE don't supply `indexOf` as a native method.